# How to check normality of a binary data(True/False) for z proportion test?

Tags: z-test

One of the three conditions that should be checked before conducting two-sampled z-test for proportions is "check for normality"(link for the source: https://vitalflux.com/two-sample-z-test-for-proportions-formula-examples/). But how can we check whether binary data is normal?[image]

Comment: Most of this is garbage.  (That's no criticism of you!)  The final paragraph is especially egregious, because the principal distinction between a Z-test and a Student t-test is that the *latter* is indicated when the SD must be estimated: that's it's original claim to fame.

Comment: ok, can you help me to understand what requirements should I check to use z-test for proportions? For example I wanna use that python package https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_ztest.html

Comment: This is extensively discussed in many of our threads about [two-sample binomial tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=two-sample+binomial+tests). You can learn about alternatives to a Z test (that is, a Normal approximation) as well as read evaluations of standard rules of thumb for applying a Z test.

Answer (score 1):

Any assumption about normality is totally violated for a binary variable: normal distributions take values on the entire real line, while binary variables take two values, and $2\ne\infty$. Consequently, that reference is wrong about this topic and likely makes mistakes on other topics, too, and I would not trust it.